# Sonar-scanner failed while loading active rules

Tags: javascript, java, sonarqube, sonarscanner, spring-framework-beans

I have SonarQube (community edition) installed through zip file. The version is 9.4. SonarScanner is installed through zip and version is 4.7. I am using macOS.

SonarQube runs fine on port 9000 and project configuration and all is done correctly. When I run the last command of SonarScanner on the root of my project directory, it fails.

Below is the command I was running

```bash
sonar-scanner \
 -Dsonar.projectKey=SalesProject \
 -Dsonar.sources=. \
 -Dsonar.host.url= http://localhost:9000 \
 -Dsonar.login=feb2c84dacaf080d46ac52214edd1b32f8784b7a
```

I am using Java 11. Below is the error stack trace.

```
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=314ms
INFO: Load active rules
WARN: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@6302bbb1-org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@6302bbb1-org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ActiveRules' defined in org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 2.059s
INFO: Final Memory: 7M/30M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@6302bbb1-org.sonar.scanner.report.ReportPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 7; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@6302bbb1-org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ActiveRules' defined in org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.SpringGlobalContainer.doAfterStart(SpringGlobalContainer.java:134)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:188)
        at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.execute(SpringComponentContainer.java:167)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedClassloader@6302bbb1-org.sonar.scanner.report.ActiveRulesPublisher': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ActiveRules' defined in org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1607)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1571)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1437)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1347)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ActiveRules' defined in org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.sonar.api.batch.rule.internal.DefaultActiveRules]: Factory method 'provide' threw exception; nested exception is org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}
        at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:36)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.DefaultScannerWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:112)
        at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.DefaultScannerWsClient.call(DefaultScannerWsClient.java:75)
        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.DefaultActiveRulesLoader.load(DefaultActiveRulesLoader.java:62)
        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:98)
        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.load(ActiveRulesProvider.java:61)
        at org.sonar.scanner.rule.ActiveRulesProvider.provide(ActiveRulesProvider.java:49)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
        ... 63 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarScanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,internalKey,templateKey,params,actives,createdAt,updatedAt,deprecatedKeys&activation=true&qprofile=AYCyQ4czTowzuVWPgEiX&ps=500&p=1 : {"errors":[{"msg":"An error has occurred. Please contact your administrator"}]}. What are the logs of sonar printing?

Comment: @pringi where to see the logs ?

Comment: You are running Sonar locally on port 9000. Consult Sonar logs whenever you've installed.